# ElasticSearch: Do I need to deploy these extra indices files of 5GB?

Tags: solr, lucene, elasticsearch

I deployed ElasticSearch to the web server. It works on local server.
But I see lots of .marvel- folders under C:\elasticsearch-1.1.1\data\elasticsearch\nodes\0\indices

The size of .marvel is 5GB of disk space.

I also see 2 folders (movies, videos) that I created index on there (see picture)

Does anyone know what are these folders for and do I need them to copy for ES to work?

[image]

Comment: No idea what you are talking about with the movies and videos directories, but the .marvel files are from ElasticSearch's [monitoring and management product, Marvel](http://www.elasticsearch.com/marvel)

Comment: You haven't read the question.

Comment: I have.  If that doesn't provide some useful information, you have failed to communicate what you want clearly.  I don't know what "that I created index on there (see picture)" is meant to convey.  As I understood the question, you wanted to know what the .marvel folders are for, and I told you.  If you don't need to know about those directories, perhaps you give a go at explaining more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I might be replying to an older question but might help some one else.

The folders in the data folder starts with .marvel* is created by the marvel plugin.

We can disable that by setting 'marvel.agent.enabled: false' in config/elasticsearch.yml.